# How to specify a Rules event like "Content is 'going to be' viewed"?

Tags: 7, rules

To answer the question about "[How to restrict access to a node via node/12 and allow access via a path like content/sometitle?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165114)", I thought it should be possible to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to do so.

I was thinking about a rule as in this exported rule (which has "***Content is viewed***" as event):

```
{ "rules_disallow_using_urls_like_node_123" : {
    "LABEL" : "Disallow using URLs like node\/123",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_view" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:path" ], "value" : "node\/[node:nid]" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "no_access" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Sorry, URLs like node\/[node:nid] are not allowed around here ..." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the challenge (and my actual question): for any node you visit, and even when visiting nodes using the path of such nodes, the rules action **always** gets executed. That makes me wonder how I can rework that "Content is viewed" event into something like "Content is 'going to be' viewed", so before Drupal is actually going to display the requested node? And this without writing a custom module.

To better explain the 'going to be'-part of it: compare it to the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)" module: if you try to visit a page for which content access is set so that you do NOT have permission to (e.g.) view it, then Drupal **will FIRST check** via content access if you do have access to it, then decides you have no permission, and then you will NOT actually be able to "view" that page (even though you asked for it). So that "will FIRST check" is similar to "going to be" ...

I also looked at the (unasnwered) question about "[I cannot see the Rules event "Page is going to be viewed"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/93806)", in which one of its comments points to [issue nr 514824](https://www.drupal.org/node/514824) (which is for D6). And in that issue there is [Fago's comment #8](https://www.drupal.org/node/514824#comment-1831428) like so:

> Use the "Content is being viewed" event when you need the node.

Assuming that was available (and working as such) in D6, what is the D7 equivalent of this event, if any? Because, obviously, my sample above seems to indicate that in D7 it doesn't work like that anymore.

**Note**: The exported source above is intentionally DISABLED, because **if** you'd want to import it and enable it, **then** it is always going to get triggered for ANY node you view. Only URLs starting with (eg) `/user` or `/admin` will not satisfy the Event in this rule (so that at least you can disable this rule again to be able to view /node paths also again).

Comment: I haven't used Rules for D7, but there indeed was an event "node is going to be viewed". You can always create a custom event to be executed on a hook_node_view. My guess is that the D7 version does not come with this feature as it can slow down the site by a great degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should react to the *System > Drupal is initializing* event and check for the URL there:

```
{ "rules_check_url" : {
    "LABEL" : "Disallow node/* access",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "site:current-page:url" ],
          "match" : "node\/\\d+$",
          "operation" : "regex"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : {
          "message" : "Sorry, URLs like [site:current-page:url] are not allowed around here ...",
          "type" : "error"
        }
      },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "no_access" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, notice that in the rule above we test against the `site:current-page:url` token, which contains the (full) original URL (as seen in the browser address bar). Checking against `site:current-page:path` would not work in this case as all nodes, even the ones being accessed via URL alias, would match.

Comment: Works perfect for what I was trying to do, so accept, and +1 !!! ... And Merci (aka "Thank you"). Though I don't understand entirely the "Also, notice ..." paragraph you added. Want to try to re-phrase that and add some more details?

Comment: Sure. Your initial rule tried to match the URL against `site:current-page:path` which is actually the internal path used by Drupal. So, for example, if your _node/233_ is aliased to _about_, then when accessing http://www.example.com/about `site:current-page:path` is going to be _node/233_, **not** _about_. So to get the actual URL you have to test against `site:current-page:path`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved redirect based on ip.

My requirement:
Show a different 'pricing' page based on country.

Default pricing page is node/7 - showing pricing in usd, node/12 is pricing page in INR

Using smart_ip module

Redirect user from pricing(node/7) to pricing.in(node/12) - if user ip is India

**Event**:

Content viewed is of type Basic page
Drupal is initializing

**Conditions**

IP address is in country
*Parameter: Country: India*
data comparison 
Parameter: Data to compare: [site:current-page:path], Data value: node/7

​**Event**

Page redirect
Parameter: URL: node/12

Exported Rule >>

```
{ "rules_pricing_page_inr" : {
"LABEL" : "Pricing page INR",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "smart_ip", "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_view--page" : { "bundle" : "page" }, "init" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "smart_ip_condition_in_country" : { "country" : { "value" : { "IN" : "IN" } } } },
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:path" ], "value" : "node\/7" } }
],
"DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "node\/12" } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, interesting variation of what my question was about. Haven't experimented (QA-tested) it yet, but just looking at your exported rule I can think situations where I might want to use this also. So thanks for sharing (and +1 ... of course)!