# Webform as a block only

Tags: webforms

When I crate a Webform I do have an option to make it available as a block as well. But in this case it creates a node as well.
How can I create a Webform as a block only?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a webform as node. Edit the node and navigate to:

Webform tab -> Form Settings tab -> Advance Settings (located at the bottom of the page).
Check the checkbox for **Available as block** and your webform will be a block.

Comment: Correct. But in this case I will get a node and a block for this Webform. But I need only a block. I don't need people get on node of this Webform...
I hope I explain clarify enough :)

Comment: @user126902 To what I am aware of using the Webforms module you will need to create a node.  Perhaps you can create a new content type and set permissions that don't allow users to view the node page.

Comment: Enable contact module, and get form URL **contact**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a solution different from the "create a webform as node" (+ make available as block).

However, to avoid anybody would want to visit that "node of the webform" (cfr. your "*I don't need people get on node of this Webform*"), you migt want to consider a variation of the approach detailed in the answer to my question "[How to specify a Rules event like "Content is 'going to be' viewed"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165155/how-to-specify-a-rules-event-like-content-is-going-to-be-viewed)". All you'd need to change to that "rule" is:

- the actual path to be checked (matching the path of your node of the webform, instead of node/*).
- and the no_access path (replace it by an appropriate path in your site).