# After "?" redirect, the url is cut, why?

Tags: 7, uri, redirection

I am using the [Anonymous Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_redirect) module to redirect `example.com` to `example.com/login`.

But when I refer a link like
`example.com/525?some=node/227` and log in, the url will be cut to `example.com/525`

I don't know why the url is cut after "`?`" or "`&`".

Any solutions for this one?

Comment: i think you need to use l() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I haven't ever used the [Anonymous Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_redirect) module, I wouldn't be surprised if your "issue" is caused by the fact that this module does not support what you're trying to do.

However, as a possible alternative (as per your "*Any solutions for this one?*"), you may want to use the Rules module to perform the redirect you want to do. For an example of how to do so, refer to my answer to "[How to redirect an anonymous user to the login form after a 403 error?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165884/how-to-redirect-an-anonymous-user-to-the-login-form-after-a-403-error/165888#165888)" (the "option 2" part of it. Not sure what exact "Rules event" would fit in your case, but it'll be probably something related to a specific "path" in your site.

Not sure if it would fit your needs here also, but maybe you want to add the "[Rules URL argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument)" module also to this. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
>
> - check if a URL argument is present.
> - compare the value of an URL argument.
>
> It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.

Refer to my answer to "[How to use the Rules module to implement a custom redirect for an outdated URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170742/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-implement-a-custom-redirect-for-an-outdated-url/170745#170745)" for way more details about this module also.