# Why 'Failed to start the session' when RedirectResponse is sent?

Tags: 8, sessions

When this code is executed, I have an error message logged.
The code is in `shared_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account)`

```
if ($node->get('nid')->value == 1) {
  if ($account->isAnonymous()) {
  }
  else {
    $path = Url::fromUserInput('/node/25')->toString();
    $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
    $response->send();
  }
}
```

The error message:

> RuntimeException : Failed to start the session because headers have
>   already been sent by
>   "/home/lejardindf/JdP8/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php" at
>   line 377. dans
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
>   (/home/lejardindf/JdP8/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php
>   ligne 150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. First, you can't send a response from custom Drupal code. Second, you can't run non access code in an access hook, because access results are cached.

For redirects in Drupal 8 see these change records: [drupal_goto() has been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537) and [hook_init() removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014).

A different approach might be to let the 403 exception happen and then catch it in an exception event subscriber to do the redirect, see [How to redirect an anonymous user to the login form after a 403 error?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165884/how-to-redirect-an-anonymous-user-to-the-login-form-after-a-403-error/245211#245211)

Comment: what do you mean by "you can't send a response from custom Drupal code"? And on that "drupal_goto() removed" page there's a snippet "Drupal 8 procedural" that looks similar to the above, essentially `(new RedirectResponse($path))->send();`. However, if I put this in a page, I do get the "Failed to start...because headers have already been sent" error.

Comment: @Max , this is not a good code example. There is no way to send a response from within a Symfony app, you have to return it from the controller. For other places see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/304037/47547

Answer (score 0):

Following @4k4's advice, I removed the code from `shared_node_access`.
Then added `shared.services.yml`:

```
services:
  shared.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\shared\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriber
    arguments: ['@current_user']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

and `EventSubscriber.php`:

```
class EventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  protected $currentUser;

  public function __construct(AccountInterface $current_user) {
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = ['redirectIf'];
    return $events;
  }

  public function redirectIf(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $node = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('node');
    if ($node && $node->get('nid')->value == 1) {
      if (!$this->currentUser->isAnonymous()) {
        $path = Url::fromUserInput('/node/25')->toString();
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($path));
      }
    }
  }
}
```