# Redirecting causes dead loop?

Tags: 8, redirection

Some of my articles are protected - allowed only if user is logged in. In case anonymous is trying to open them page "Access denied. You are not authorized to access this page." is displayed, which is ok - that works well.

Now, I want instead of showing them that page to redirect then to login page. I created event subscriber which looks like:

```
class RedirectAnonymousSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function checkAuthStatus(GetResponseEvent $event) {

    global $base_url;

    if (
      \Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous() &&
      \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'system.403') {

      $response = new RedirectResponse($base_url . '/user/login', 301);
      $event->setResponse($response);
      $event->stopPropagation();
      return;
    }
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkAuthStatus');
    return $events;
  }
}
```

When debugging I saw that this "Access denied" page has "system.403" route name so I'm checking if user is anonymous and also that page is displayed. In that case I'm doing redirection to login page. However I end up in unlimited redirection loop with this code?!

I just don't see what the problem is here?

Comment: do you by any chance have redirect configured for that restricted page in redirects ?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login

Comment: Thank you @Kevin, that did the trick. However I'm still interested why my code is not working.

Comment: The page for system.403 is built in a sub-request. You have to handle the 403 before it reaches the sub-request by using an exception subscriber. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245211/47547

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect an anonymous user to the login form after a 403 error?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165884/how-to-redirect-an-anonymous-user-to-the-login-form-after-a-403-error)