# How to redirect a URL to the members page of a group?

Tags: 7, rules, group

Following this question :

[How to limit access of a view about Group Memberships to the Group's administrator?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221391/how-to-limit-access-of-a-view-about-group-memberships-to-the-groups-administrat/221502?noredirect=1#)

How to redirect URLs :

/group/memberlist/gid

To the members page of a group :

/group/gid/memberlist

thank you in advance

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens This is my new question. I do not know if it's clear

Comment: To me the question is clear!