# What rule to use to redirect users, unless already redirected?

Tags: 7, rules, redirection

I'd like users with certain roles to be redirected to the page /civicrm when they login, unless they've already been redirected elsewhere. For example, an email might have a link that directs them to the page /elsewhere.

When I tried the module '[login destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination)' I can only achieve one or the other, never both - either the redirect works but a regular login doesn't redirect to /civicrm or the other way round.

From browsing in Drupal Answers, I'm pretty sure that Rules could do this, but I've tried and failed so far.  The rule needs 2 conditions to be satisfied - user is one of the roles, and they are not already being redirected - then they should be directed to /civicrm.

Can anyone please suggest how a rule might achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make a flag on users: 'flag_user_has_logged_out', you will need more than one rule, first rule: react on: user has logged out, and flag the user with this new flag, on another rule: react on logged_in: first validate your roles, then validate if user is 'flagged' if so, redirect to /whatever, and unflag user has logged out. if not, the other redirect will take control. This kind of rules i use a lot, i make many calculations on user has logged-out and i do not need to recalculate things again when user loggs in, it work both ways, maybe user just clossed browser and did not made a logged-out, so a evalutate that when loggs in and i do not duplicate my calculations. i hope you understood me and help you. is just a pointing directions on what you can do. Examples how your rules will look like:

[image: user has logged out]

[image: user has logged in]

Comment: how do you flag a user who "***...has logged out***"?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xyq0Ej4.png

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this to work, using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, using the "**Drupal is initializing**" event. That will ensure that the rule gets triggered BEFORE the actual content is shown. Using Rules event " *Content is viewed* " is typically 'too late'. Refer to '[How to specify a Rules event like "Content is 'going to be' viewed"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/165155/39516)' for more details on that. Adapt your rule to use this event, combine that with the relevant Rules conditions (like roles, etc) and, just for temporary unit testing, add a Rules Action (as the very first Rules Action) to "Show a message on a site", e.g to say '*Bingo, let the Rules party begin (we did find a Rules Event to continue building on)*'.

Comment: Thanks - your answer is appreciated and I have learnt a lot with this episode.  I found that there was a module R4032login installed that I wasn't aware of which was obviously making things difficult. Embarrassing I guess but there you go!